# Docker container not connecting to any networks

Tags: python, docker, networking

I am trying to containerize a python script (I didn't write the script and know very little python) so it can easily interact with one of my containers. I want this script to run on the same docker network as my other containers, which in this case is a user-defined bridge network called `my_network`. When using docker-compose, I am able to easily specify the network with `Networks: - my_network`. However, when I try to do that for this image, it does not seem to connect to `my_network`. I've also tried manually changing the network with `docker network connect my_network container1` but `docker inspect container` still returns this:

```
"Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "4cdc5abac597941053605ec4edd4ffff39038e154987d7aa6ad6265ea4d1cb3b",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

[docker-compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/zvJrxs6q)

[Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/iUQx7qHW)

Why is this happening? Do I have to configure something in either the script or the Dockerfile in order to enable networking? I have never created or modified an image before, nor do I know very much python, so I will need a somewhat spoonfed answer if possible. Thanks!

Comment: How are you launching the container?  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that describes the network environment you get by default?  Can you add some details like your `docker-compose.yml` file to the question?

Comment: Added docker-compose. Yes, I've read through that a few times. I understand for the most part how to use networks that have been created, but this container for my script does not seem to be able to connect to any of the docker networks for some reason... I don't get `qbtdownloadcleaner_default` when I leave out the network specification in my compose file for example.